# Best way of cloning (compiled) regex_t struct in C

Tags: c, regex

Looking to the [regex_t man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex), there is a `regcomp()` function that compiles a `regex_t` struct from a string and a dual function `regfree()` to free the `regex_t` (I understand that freeing is needed due to `regex_t` uses some dynamic memory internally).

However, that manual page doesn't mention a function to clone a compiled `regex_t` into another `regex_t` struct. Is there any way of doing that?

The only mechanism that I can figure out is re-compiling from the source string, but I guess that is less efficient than just copy at `regex_t`level.

Answer (score 0):

Why "clone"?  The `regex_t` doesn't hold any information about inputs it was compared to (with `regexec`).  It's just a "compiled" version of the regular expression.  You don't have to copy it.  Just use it.

Comment: In my application, I have a `regex_t` object that is part of another class named StringFilterItem (detail here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/d6969490c8db77b2147fccbd986aab49303b5e8c/src/lib/rest/StringFilter.h#L115). I need to copy instances of StringFilterItem class, including all their internal elements, including the compiled `regex_t` field. At the present moment I'm re-compiling the regex (as the original regex string is part of StringFilterItem) but I asked at SOF in order to know if a more efficient mechanism exists.

Comment: If I were you, I'd keep the string and recompile it, just to be safe.  It simply can't be that **regcomp** figures in your system's performance.  Or, provided there's no chance of simultaneous use, I'd live dangerously and use a copy of the `regex_t`, on the assumption that any pointers it maintains are only read, and it doesn't matter from where.  Any advice you'd get would be implementation-specific, and subject to change.